# How to fix SSL error while downloading a python package

Tags: python

while downloading gensim on windows machine i am getting error There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate.

Have checked multiple threads on SO and youtube as well but unable to fix the issue. The same issue is appearing for some other packages as well. Tried loading the package from anaconda as well as from pip

```
pip install gensim

conda install -c conda-forge gensim
```

> The error reads as :
>   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/gensim/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/gensim/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping

Comment: What version of windows are you using ?

Comment: Are you at work?

Comment: Yes correct. This is a work machine